# debubbing 3x pageviews in google analytics

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics

There seems to be something causing 3x the pageviews that are supposed to happen, Seems there is one universal  analytics code sending page view and a global tag page view + other analytics code, thing is, there is no way to find said code inside the Wordpress to remove them. How would you search for this if it were you?

Here is the website (hid the url for privacy of the person, after the question was solved)

Comment: Is page tracking called several times, is the google script included more than one time?

Comment: You've got UA- referenced three times in your code. One actually doesn't even have Google Tag Manager configured right (tag ID is missing). If it were configured, all your UA code should be pulled there as a variable/tag. There's another after you pull in your js codes, so likely near your enqueues. The last is called after Slider Revolution's meta.. so probably a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into your header.php to edit anything inside  in Wordpress. This file is in Appearance -> Editor option. If you are new, I recommend you to back up your site first.

Also look into plugins that add headers and footers.

EDIT 1 - found one file in your root folder by the name of google_analytics_auto.js - this has old ga.js

EDIT 2 - second one is inside a plugin implementation named 'Above the fold optimization'. [Link to the plugin](https://github.com/wp-plugins/above-the-fold-optimization) this contains analytics.js

Comment: found one file in your root folder by the name of google_analytics_auto.js

Comment: second one is inside a plugin implementation named 'Above the fold optimization'.

Comment: eliminated the folder you specified, tracking has gone down to 2x, now ill delete the plugin and see if its done. You are great mate.